# Is it possible to create an autosize constraint for a cell that hosts an inner UITableView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, cirrious.fluentlayout

I have a layout that requires an MvxTableViewCell to render an inner UITableView.  I can get the layouts working pretty nicely with FluentLayout except that I can't seem to get the hosting cell to render until I set a static height. The problem with this approach is that I'd like the cell to only occupy the space needed for the inner UITableView without having potential extra space because of a static size (which feels dirty in any event). Any idea how I can tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.  I know this makes me look idiotic, but I think I've found the start of my answer here:

[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Apologies for cluttering the internet.